# Align Text with padding SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uilabel

I am creating a view that looks like this -

[image: required view]

I am struggling to align the summary text with the text inside the image overlay.

I would like the leading edge of *Research* to align with the leading edge of *My experience*.

At the moment my view is rendering as

[image: first attempt]

As you can see text view is too close to the leading edge.

I have tried adding `.padding()` but the view changes to

[image: second attempt]

How can I properly inset the text so these 2 components line up?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      FeaturedContentCard()
        .frame(minHeight: 100)
    }.padding()
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}

struct FeaturedContentCard: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ImageWithTextOverlayView(image: "featured_image", text: "My experience with EAP and Income Protection")
      ContentCardSummary(text: "Research shows that our social enviroment significantly impacts our biology")
        .padding(.all)
      ContentCardMetaView(readTime: "10 min read", name: "Jessica Bell")
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 16)
    .background(Color.white)
    .feedItemContainer()
  }
}


struct ImageWithTextOverlayView: View {

  private(set) var image: String
  private(set) var text: String

  var body: some View {
    Image(image)
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
      .overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6536279966)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0))]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
      .overlay(
        Text(text)
          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
          .font(.title)
          .padding(),
        alignment: .bottomLeading
    )
  }
}

struct ContentCardSummary: View {
  private(set) var text: String
  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
      .frame(alignment: .leading)
      .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.2901960784, alpha: 1)))
  }
}


struct FeedItemContainer: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
      .customShadow()
  }
}

struct BenefexShadow: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .shadow(color: Color(.init(red: 0.18, green: 0.18, blue: 0.18, alpha: 0.16)).opacity(1), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 1)
      .shadow(color: Color(.init(red: 0.18, green: 0.18, blue: 0.18, alpha: 0.1)).opacity(1), radius: 60, x: 0, y: 4)
      .shadow(color: Color(.init(red: 0.18, green: 0.18, blue: 0.18, alpha: 0.16)).opacity(1), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 1)
  }
}


extension View {

  func customShadow() -> some View {
    self.modifier(BenefexShadow())
  }

  func feedItemContainer() -> some View {
    self.modifier(FeedItemContainer())
  }
}

struct AvatarView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Image("profile_pic")
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
      .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
      .clipShape(Circle())
      .overlay(
        Circle()
          .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
    )
      .customShadow()
  }
}

struct ContentCardMetaView: View {
  private(set) var readTime: String
  private(set) var name: String
  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 8) {
      AvatarView()
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(readTime)
          .font(.subheadline)
          .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.2901960784, alpha: 1)))
        Text(name)
          .fontWeight(.medium)
          .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2980392157, green: 0.1843137255, blue: 0.737254902, alpha: 1)))
      }
      Spacer()
      Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
          .font(.system(size: 24))
          .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7803921569, green: 0.7803921569, blue: 0.7803921569, alpha: 1)))
          .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is fix. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

1) Remove padding at top layer, so

```
  ImageWithTextOverlayView(image: "large_image", text: "My experience with EAP and Income Protection")
  ContentCardSummary(text: "Research shows that our social enviroment significantly impacts our biology")
  ContentCardMetaView(readTime: "10 min read", name: "Jessica Bell")
```

2) Correct alignment of summary, as

```
struct ContentCardSummary: View {
  private(set) var text: String
  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // << full width
      .padding() // << same padding as above text
      .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.2901960784, alpha: 1)))
  }
}
```